# How to install kubernetes using automatic deb version?

Tags: kubernetes

I use ubuntu 20.04 (focal) and need use kubernetes but the official package is `kubernetes-xenial` and the snap version is broken and no have support.

How to create a command for install automatic last compatible version of deb file kubernete?

The address of packages is https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists but i need create a bash script to detect the latest package directory, but the directory listing not contains the date of each file.

Need make a switch statement from bash with all ubuntu versions and modify when canonical add a new release?

Comment: If the snap is broken, have you reported it? Be patient: For most of those engineers, today is a weekend.

Comment: The official channel to report the snap kubeadm package is only by email address. Yes, i report it, the kubeadm can not comunicate with snap docker service. The kubeadm repository issues says: the problem is the snap package, send the problem to canonical, but canonical has not have a ticket system for issues and launchpad says: send a email to canonical.